# Getting processDebugResources error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting an error when I try to compile the project in android studio like this,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:\adt-bundle-  
windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0_rc2\aapt.exe'' finished with  
non-zero exit value 1
```

What is the reason for this? How to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. There was a png image inside mipmap folders named default and renaming that name to a different name solved the issue.